# Why do TV and movie opening credits single out some cast members by displaying the character's name as well as that of the actors?

Tags: credits

For example, I was watching Indiana Jones:  The Last Crusade.  The opening credits listed a bunch of actors, ending with "And Sean Connery as Professor Harry Jones".  I remember watching Star Trek: The Next Generation and they would always do this for "Whoopi Goldberg as Guinan" or "Jean de Lancie as Q".

(Please note:  This question is in reference to credits displayed in the opening sequence of an episode or film.  This is not in reference to credits as they are displayed on IMDB).

Comment: also - https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/1551/in-opening-credits-for-tv-shows-why-does-it-say-with-so-and-so-for-some-actor?rq=1

Comment: and - https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/1468/what-rules-govern-how-tv-show-opening-credits-are-structured

Comment: **Definitely** not a dupe of your first one, @Paulie_D.  That's asking why their name is listed that way on IMDB.

Answer (score 5):

According to the [New England Film website](https://newenglandfilm.com/magazine/2012/08/credits) article titled "**OPENING CREDITS: WHO, WHAT, WHERE, WHEN AND WHY**":

> **THE “AND” ACTOR**
>
> A step up from the “with” acting credit, the final title card for the
>   cast is reserved for the actor who has a meaty part in the movie, but
>   not a leading role. It’s like, wow, isn’t it amazing that Big Actor
>   blessed this movie with his presence, and I bet he’s gonna be great!
>
> It’s where the elder statesman is listed, the uber-star. Many times
>   the character’s name is listed here as well, such as “And Sam Elliott
>   as The Stranger” from The Big Lebowski.